# Scripting select elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, select

I find it difficult to style and even add event listeners for the html select element.

**Expected Behavior**
I want to alert the text content of a select option.

This is the HTML code:

```
<select name="chooseSub" id="chooseSub" placeholder="Here we go">
  <option value="makeChoice" id="disabled">--Make a choice-- </option>
  <option value="ai" id="ai">Artificial Intelligence</option>
  <option value="angularJs" id="angularJs">AngularJs</option>
  <option value="css" id="css3">CSS3</option>
</select>
```

And this is the javascript code:

```
var select = document.getElementById('chooseSub');

select.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target && event.target.nodeName === 'option') {
    alert(event.target);
  }
});
```

**Actual Behavior**
It does not do anything at all

Comment: try putting alert(event.target.nodeName) right before the 'if' (hint: it isn't 'option').

Answer (score 0):

Did you meen this?

```js
var select = document.getElementById('chooseSub');

select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.selectedOptions[0].text);
});
```

```html
<select name="chooseSub" id="chooseSub" placeholder="Here we go">
  <option value="makeChoice" id="disabled">--Make a choice-- </option>
  <option value="ai" id="ai">Artificial Intelligence</option>
  <option value="angularJs" id="angularJs">AngularJs</option>
  <option value="css" id="css3">CSS3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(opt){
alert(opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].text);
/*if you want value of selected option : alert(opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].value);*/
}
```

```html
<select name="chooseSub" id="chooseSub" placeholder="Here we go" onChange='myFunction(this)'>
  <option value="makeChoice" id="disabled">--Make a choice-- </option>
  <option value="ai" id="ai">Artificial Intelligence</option>
  <option value="angularJs" id="angularJs">AngularJs</option>
  <option value="css" id="css3">CSS3</option>
</select>
```